# Created the forward and reverse zone files but having this

Tags: linux, dns-zone

here is the file

```
$TTL 86400
@       IN SOA  master.git-gotech.net. (
                                        0       ; serial
                                        3600    ; refresh
                                        1800    ; retry
                                        604800  ; expire
                                        864000 )        ; minimum

@ IN   NS master.git-gotech.net
@ IN   A 10.1.10.189

master  IN A 10.1.10.189
jessica-vm1.gitgotech.net  IN  A 10.1.10.159
```

Error message

```
near eol: unexpected end of input zone forward/IN:
```

Comment: Note that DNS zone file shorthand is tricky.  FQDN's must be terminated with a `.` lest they be considered a relative hostname. In shorthand a domain gets appended to relative names, which is what allows you to use `master IN A 10.1.10.189` rather than `master.gitgotech.net. IN A 10.1.10.189` but that also means that `jessica-vm1.gitgotech.net  IN  A 10.1.10.159` (missing that trailing dot) will also parsed as shorthand and becomes a resource record for `jessica-vm1.gitgotech.net.gitgotech.net.` and `@ IN   NS master.git-gotech.net` becomes `master.git-gotech.net.git-gotech.net.`

Answer (score 1):

Your SOA record is wrong. After `IN SOA` there should be a nameserver and an email address of the person responsible for the zone (with a dot instead of "@"), like this:

```
@ IN SOA master.git-gotech.net. admin.git-gotech.net. (0 3600 1800 604800 864000 )
```

Comment: thanks for the correction . it worked